# Value of a field attribute on a proc macro

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I have this struct:

```
pub struct Thing {
    pub some_field: i32,

    #[my_attr = some_value]
    pub field_attr: String
}
```

How can I recover the data on the right side of the equals? I can recover perfectly fine the left side.

```
pub fn new(name: &Ident, raw_helper_attributes: &[Attribute], ty: &Type) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        // Getting the name of attributes put in front of struct fields
        let helper_attributes = raw_helper_attributes
            .iter()
            .map(|attribute| {
                attribute
                    .path
                    .segments
                    .iter()
                    .map( |segment| {
                        &segment.ident
                    })
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            })
            .flatten()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();

        let attribute_type = if helper_attributes.len() == 1 {
            let helper_attribute = helper_attributes[0];
            Some(EntityFieldAnnotation::try_from(helper_attribute)?)
        } else if helper_attributes.len() > 1 {
            return Err(
                syn::Error::new_spanned(
                    name, 
                    "Field has more than one attribute"
                )
            );
        } else { None };

        Ok(
            Self {
                name: name.clone(),
                field_type: ty.clone(),
                attribute: attribute_type,
            }
        )
    }
```

For short, I ommited the rest of the code of the macro for summarize.

Comment: What is the syntax of `some_value`?

Comment: An `&str` representing some random ascii value

Comment: Is it an identifier (`#[my_attr = my_value]`) or string literal  (`#[my_attr = "my_value"]`), or either, or something else?

Comment: It's just a string literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Attribute::parse_meta()`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.Attribute.html#method.parse_meta):

```rust
let (path, value) = match attribute.parse_meta().unwrap() {
    syn::Meta::NameValue(syn::MetaNameValue {
        path,
        lit: syn::Lit::Str(s),
        ..
    }) => (path, s.value()),
    _ => panic!("malformed attribute syntax"),
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not being able to impl your solution. Can you provide it in the context of the code? Or another workaround? I can't even compile the first line. `Value is not found on this scope`.

Comment: Oh, I always swap the order. It should be `lit: value`. Will edit.

Comment: @Pyzyryab I don't really grasp the intent in your code (why do you flatten the paths?) So I cannot help you more (and in additiona, this is not a question for SO. If you're stuck at something, please explain exactly where), but this should give you the main idea.

Comment: oh, forgot about this. Your answer is perfectly ok